# Script warning in WPF WebBrowser

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi there I want a great HTML editor in WPF. So for this what I did is that I added a WebBrowser to WPF window and navigated it to the html page with the TinyMCE html editor in it. However when I run the app, the browser control shows the script warning: (please refer to this MSDN thread for images http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/cbc3eae6-dbc4-4074-befc-902d990fbaae)

I tried the COM code posted by Simon Mourier on StackOverflow here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138199/wpf-webbrowser-control-how-to-supress-script-errors)

Now my Code look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Reflection;

namespace TinyMceWpf
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.Navigated += new NavigatedEventHandler(webBrowser1_Navigated);
            webBrowser1.Navigate(new
Uri(@"C:\Users\MAHESH\Desktop\TechNode\WPF\MytTechDos\TinyMceWpf\TinyMceWpf\TinyMceWpf\edit.html"));
        }


        private void btnGetHtml_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string editHtml = this.webBrowser1.InvokeScript("getContent").ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(editHtml);
        }

    public static void SetSilent(WebBrowser browser, bool silent)
    {
        if (browser == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("browser");

        // get an IWebBrowser2 from the document
        IOleServiceProvider sp = browser.Document as IOleServiceProvider;
        if (sp != null)
        {
            Guid IID_IWebBrowserApp = new Guid("0002DF05-0000-0000-C000-000000000046");
            Guid IID_IWebBrowser2 = new Guid("D30C1661-CDAF-11d0-8A3E-00C04FC9E26E");

            object webBrowser;
            sp.QueryService(ref IID_IWebBrowserApp, ref IID_IWebBrowser2, out webBrowser);
            if (webBrowser != null)
            {
                webBrowser.GetType().InvokeMember("Silent", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.PutDispProperty, null, webBrowser, new object[] { silent });
            }
        }
    }


    [ComImport, Guid("6D5140C1-7436-11CE-8034-00AA006009FA"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    private interface IOleServiceProvider
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        int QueryService([In] ref Guid guidService, [In] ref Guid riid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] out object ppvObject);
    }

    private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        SetSilent(webBrowser1, true);
    }
}
}
```

But it is still not working till now. What should I do? Please help.

Comment: When you enabled the script the error went away.  What specifically is the problem?

Comment: Yes when I enabled the script the error went away. But I dont want the script error to come at all when I run the app and the WebBrowser control is navigated to the html page that contains the tinyMce.

Comment: oop sorry for that. Actually I use to quickly go through the response and then implement and experiment with it. So in that I feel that I forgot to mark them as answer. But I am seriously puzzled how I did not marked none of them as answer. My mistake. I now marked them. Yes thanks to point to this.

Answer (score 3):

Use this code in your SetSilent method.

```
FieldInfo webBrowserInfo = browser.GetType().GetField("_axIWebBrowser2", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
object comWebBrowser = null;

if (webBrowserInfo != null)
   comWebBrowser = webBrowserInfo.GetValue(browser);

if (comWebBrowser != null)
   comWebBrowser.GetType().InvokeMember("Silent", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, comWebBrowser, new object[] { silent });
```

Comment: What is the `silent` object in the last line?

Comment: The last flag is `bool silent`.  See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3190790/787893