# Loading a website inside WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I've been playing with loading a website (specifically my blog) inside a WebBrowser in WPF.  My code is pretty much just one line:

```
WebBrowser.Source = new Uri("http://www.example.net");
```

When I run this I get scripting error, like this:

[image: Script Error]

I get similar errors when running other web sites, although not always related to Google Ads.

My assumption is that there is an issue with sites that run JS.  Is this correct and, if so, why?  Is there a way around it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I suppress script errors when using the WPF WebBrowser control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298255/how-do-i-suppress-script-errors-when-using-the-wpf-webbrowser-control)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the WPF WebBrowser did not implement this property as in the 2.0 control. But with reflection you can get to the activexinstance of the webbrowser control to put the browser in silent mode:

```
dynamic activeX = this.WB.GetType().InvokeMember("ActiveXInstance",
                    BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                    null, this.WB, new object[] { });

activeX.Silent = true;
```

Comment: There is no such property on the WebBrowser control