# WPF Webbrowser control javascript error dialog

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf

I'm using the default web browser WPF control in an closed down kiosk type system (.NET 4.5) running Windows 8.1. The problem is that we need to disable the javscript error dialogs.

[javscript error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTUXQ.png)

"Disabled script debugging (IE) & Others" and "Disable a notification about every script error" are enabled.

I already tried injecting this in the document on the onNavigating and onNavigated events

`function noError() { return true; } window.onerror = noError;`

but it doesn't work. Setting the `silent` settings is not an option.
Also using the WindowsFormsHost and ScriptErrorsSuppressed are non-viable options.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I suppress script errors when using the WPF WebBrowser control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298255/how-do-i-suppress-script-errors-when-using-the-wpf-webbrowser-control)

Comment: It is't a duplicate because I stated clearly that SuppressScriptErrors or the silent setting (from the Forms control) is not an option.